# How can I use plot's style=line in pine script 4

Tags: pine-script

I've tried line.style_solid, but it doesn't work. This is the code.

> plot(close, title = "Close", color = color.blue, linewidth = 2, **style = line**)

This error appeared

> Undeclared identifier 'line'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(close, title = "Close", color = color.blue, linewidth = 2, style =plot.style_line)
```